# Iterating over timestamp files and comparing them with current date

Tags: bash, time, timestamp, type-conversion

I am trying to iterate over files that are in Unix Timestamp format. I am using Bash. For example those files look like this (it is in milliseconds):

```
1658319357014.txt
```

I want to choose those files that has Unix Timestamp greater than current date.

So the first problem is how to get only year, month and day and convert it to UNIX timestamp. This is how I am doing it:

```
CURRENT_DATE=$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=$(date +d "$CURRENT_DATE" +%s000)
```

While doing it I am facing "date: illegal time format". I was thinking maybe it is because I am using MAC OS. 000 is added to convert timestamp to miliseconds.

Second problem that I have is comparing name of the file with current date. I tried to hardcode date in UNIX Timestamp and compare it but it still was not working. I think this is is because im comparing string values and while comparing string values it checks for length or last dights if it is the same. So how can I compare string values as numbers? Moreover that files has extension .txt and my CURRENT_TIMESTAMP does not.

EIDT:
I manged to get current year-month-day and the problem was that my operating system is MAC OS so i had to use

```
date -jf "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S" "$(date +%Y-%m-%d-0-0-1)" "+%s"000
```

Comment: How do you compare the values?

Comment: It is working on on Linux indeed but on MAC OS it iss throwing an error
date: illegal option -- d
because MAC OS has different options and it should be -jf

Answer (score 0):

Use `-d` instead of `+d`.

```
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=$(date -d "$CURRENT_DATE" +%s000)
#                        ~
```

The timestamps should have the same length unless you have really old files (created before September 9 2001) or a time machine. Therefore, you should be able to use both string and numeric comparison.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP=$(date -d "$CURRENT_DATE" +%s000)

for v in 1658319357014 1688316312345 ; do
    if [[ $CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > $v ]] ; then
        echo ">"
    else
        echo "<="
    fi

    if (( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP > v )) ; then
        echo ">"
    else
        echo "<="
    fi
done
```